# Why am I only targeting panel4 (not the clicked panel) when adding event listeners via a getElementsByClassName array

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, getelementsbyclassname

The expected result is that when you click on each panel, the panel you clicked on moves, then moves back when you click it again.

The result with my current code is that no matter which panel you click it is always panel4 that toggles.

The reason these need to be added dynamically to each is because this list of panels will be auto populated and have the target ids dynamically generated too.

The Code....

```js
var plbelements = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
for (var l = 0; l < plbelements.length; l++) {
  targetPanel = document.getElementById(plbelements[l].id);
  actionSwipeAmount = "160px";
  console.log("Target Panel before event listener = " + targetPanel.id);
  targetPanel.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    left = window.getComputedStyle(targetPanel).getPropertyValue("left");
    console.log(targetPanel.id);
    if (left != actionSwipeAmount) {
      targetPanel.style.left = actionSwipeAmount;
    } else {
      targetPanel.style.left = "0px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.panelsContainer {
  display: block;
  max-width: 360px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.underPanel {
  display: block;
  width: 360px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #6c6c6c;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
.panel {
  display: block;
  width: 360px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #141414;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.underPanel:nth-child(even) > .panel {
  background-color: #303030;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div class="panelsContainer">
  <div class="underPanel">Hello
    <div id="panel1" class="panel">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="underPanel">Hello
    <div id="panel2" class="panel">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="underPanel">Hello
    <div id="panel3" class="panel">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="underPanel">Hello
    <div id="panel4" class="panel">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For solving your problem, you need to redefine the target variable in for loop using const like this:

```
    const targetPanel = document.getElementById(plbelements[l].id);
```

And you'd better use const and let instead of var. The entire JavaScript code is as follows:

```
    const plbelements = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");

    for (let l = 0; l < plbelements.length; l++) {
        const targetPanel = document.getElementById(plbelements[l].id);
        const actionSwipeAmount = "160px";
        console.log("Target Panel before event listener = " + targetPanel.id);

        targetPanel.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            left = window.getComputedStyle(targetPanel).getPropertyValue("left");
            console.log(targetPanel.id);

            if (left != actionSwipeAmount) {
                targetPanel.style.left = actionSwipeAmount;
            } else {
                targetPanel.style.left = "0px";
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm guessing this is to do with a const cannot be updated or re-declared but as I was using a var it was being re-declared each time in the loop and thus being set at the last value declared?

Comment: This link will help you to understand javascript scope. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp